# How can I figure out how much white a color is mixed with to create another color?

Tags: sass, colors

Say I have **color1** `#0c3058` and **color2** `#466280` and I **know** that color2 is color1 mixed with a certain percentage of white. How can I figure out how much white?

In this example I know the answer is 24%, and I create color2 in Sass using mix(#fff, #0c3058, 24%). I want to know how I can figure it out for other combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up looking up how the Sass `mix()` function works, and found [this JavaScript code that recreates its functionality](https://gist.github.com/jedfoster/7939513).

I borrowed its h2d function:
`function h2d(h) { return parseInt(h, 16); } // convert a hex value to decimal`

And I looked at how it mixes the colors:

```
// combine the current pairs from each source color, according to the specified weight
val = d2h(Math.floor(v2 + (v1 - v2) * (weight / 100.0)));
```

I already know one of my colors is white, and that all its RGB values are all 255. I replaced `v2` with 255.

Since I'm comparing to white I can choose to test R, G, or B, they will all give me the same result.

So I attempted to do algebra, failed, asked for help, and got this equation out of the original one:

```
100 * (c2 - 255) / (c1 - 255) = x
```

Where:

- c1 = R(ed) for the original color
- c2 = R(ed) for the final mixed color
- x = the color weight in the mix
- 100 - x = the white weight in the mix

```js
//based on https://gist.github.com/jedfoster/7939513

function h2d(h) { return parseInt(h, 16); } // convert a hex value to decimal 

var unmix = function() {
  color_1 = document.getElementById('color1').value;
  color_2 = document.getElementById('color2').value;
  
  var c1 = h2d(color_1.substr(0, 2));
  var c2 = h2d(color_2.substr(0, 2)); 
  
  document.getElementById('percents').value = 100 - Math.floor((100 * (c2 - 255) / (c1 - 255)));
}
```

```html
<label for="color1" />Color 1</label>
<input id="color1" value="0c3058" />
<label for="color2">Color 2</label>
<input id="color2" value="466280" />
<button onclick="unmix()">Figure Out White Color Weight</button>
<input id="percents" />
```